# preact compat causing component to mount infinitely

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, preact

I have working reactjs app with redux and react router. 
I want to switch to preact. 
When I updated webpack config to alias react and react dom. 
Component started mounting infinitely. It mount then unmount .. goes on doing so. 
Webpack config.

```
alias: {
        "react": path.resolve(__dirname, 'react.js'),
        "react-dom": path.resolve(__dirname, 'react.js')
        },
```

react.js

```
var preact = require('preact-compat');
var react = {};
Object.keys(preact).forEach(function(key) {
  react[key] = preact[key];
});

module.exports = react;
```

This file is because I am using react hot loader. 
React app is working fine .. but adding preact has bug. pls guide me.

Comment: Why aren't you using [the documented method](https://github.com/developit/preact-compat#usage-with-webpack) of replacing React and ReactDOM?

Comment: I have done that.. but it caused another error. which I have fixed with above code.

Comment: So you fixed one issue by introducing another. What was the other error?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property createElement of #<Object> which has only a getter

Comment: Ohh yeah, I remember that error from my own project. I resolved it by not using `preact-compact` in combination with `react-hot-loader`, because (AFAIK) those two just don't work together.

Comment: after removing hot loader .. it is working fine .. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, `preact-compat` and React Hot Loader (RHL) don't work together very well (it's still on the TODO list of the developer of `preact-compact`, see [this comment](https://github.com/developit/preact-compat/issues/337#issuecomment-296867409)).

I work around these issues myself by not combining the two, i.e. use the "real" React and ReactDOM when I want to use RHL, or use `preact-compat` when I don't need RHL.